# Filtering a list by 5 files per directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

SO i have a list of files inside a tree of folders

```
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/2
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/3
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/4
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/5
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/6
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/7
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/8
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/9
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/10
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/1
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/2
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/3
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/4
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/5
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/6
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/7
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/8
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/9
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/10
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/1
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/2
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/3
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/4
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/5
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/6
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/7
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/8
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/9
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/10
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/1
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/2
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/3
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/4
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/5
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/6
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/7
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/8
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/9
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/10
```

I want to basically filter out the content of this list so I only have the highest 5 numbers for each directory.
Any ideas?

preferable in bash/shell

Expected Output:(small sample size cause of SO says too much code)

```
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/6
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/7
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/8
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/9
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/example/10
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/6
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/7
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/8
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/9
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/test/other/10
```

Thanks

edit - using `for i in $(for i in  $(dirname $(find $(pwd) -type f -name "*[0-9]*" | sort -V) | uniq) ;do ls  $i | sort -V |tail -n 5 ; done) ; do readlink -f $i ; done` works for a small sample size. However expanding said sample appears to long for dirname

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share what have you tried so far

Comment: Tried using tail but only spits out last 5 for the whole list .  
Try editing the find command i used to get here 
`find $(pwd) -type f -name "*[0-9]*" | sort -V `
But can seem to find a way to filter it per directory

Comment: What is the expected output for the sample given?

Comment: I've amended it in the original post, too long for comments

Comment: @dgoo3889 Commands dirname and basename might be helpful for you.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg thanks for these, right now i've got this  
`for i in $(for i in  $(dirname $(find $(pwd) -type f -name "*[0-9]*" | sort -V) | uniq) ;do ls  $i | sort -V |tail -n 5 ; done) ; do readlink -f $i ; done` pretty convoluted if anyone knows a way to clean it up a bit

Although when trying on a longer list of files. it appears to long for dirname to handle :/

Comment: Check my answer using `awk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input data is **sorted**.
Try:

```
awk -F'/[^/]*$'  '{if (NR==1 || prev_dir == $1) {i=i+1} else {i=1}; if ( i<=5){ prev_dir=$1 ; print $0}; }'
```

Explanation:

`'/[^/]*$'` <-- Set regex delimiter to get directory base-name as first field

`if (NR==1 || prev_dir == $1) {i=i+1} else {i=1};`  <-- Check file is from same directory. if yes increment counter by 1 else reset.

`if ( i<=5){ prev_dir=$1 ; print $0}; }'` <-- Print first 5 records of current directory.

Demo:

```
$awk -F'/[^/]*$'  '{if (NR==1 || prev_dir == $1) {i=i+1} else {i=1}; if ( i<=5){ prev_dir=$1 ; print $0 }; }' temp.txt
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/2
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/3
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/4
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/5
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/6
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/1
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/2
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/3
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/4
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/5
$cat temp.txt 
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/2
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/3
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/4
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/5
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/6
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/7
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/8
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/9
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/folder2/10
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/1
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/2
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/3
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/4
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/5
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/6
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/7
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/8
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/9
/home/user/Scripts/example/tmp/other_folder/files/10
$
```

Comment: You can use `sort` to make sure it's sorted.

Comment: But the OP wants the greatest 5 numbers. This prints out the least 5.

Comment: @LxerLx OP can sort data in reverse.

Comment: How could the OP sort the data so that the program would give the output expected by the OP? Apparently, the above program isn't an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation in plain bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

prevdir=

while read -r line; do
    dir=${line%/*}
    [[ $dir == "$prevdir" ]] || { n=0; prevdir=$dir; }
    ((n++ < 5)) && echo "$line"
done
```

You can use it like:

```
./script < file.list # If file.list already sorted by a reverse version sort
```

or,

```
sort -rV file.list | ./script # If the file.list is not sorted
```

or,

```
find /home/user/Scripts -type f | sort -rV | ./script
```

Also, you may want to append `| tac` to the pipelines above.